# Vertical Center Align BS4 Card Title

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Creating a card with bootstrap 4. Can't seem to **vertically center** the card title when using the `<h>` tag. As you can see from my example code, I've tried a number of bootstrap classes to align, but none seem to do the trick. My best guess was `align-middle`, however no result. I've also tried a `.d-flex` + `align-self-center`

I can do this with CSS, but there must be a BS4 solution without creating custom CSS. Is there a way to do this with BS4?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card border-info" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="card-header text-white bg-info">
    <h6 class="align-middle">Example Title</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You try removing the `margin-bottom` of your `h6`? `<h6 class="align-middle mb-0">Example Title</h6>`

Comment: @zgood that worked, but what if I wanted to keep the margin?

Comment: Well then to keep it centered you would have to add the same margin to the top. i.e. add the class `my-2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

Added `d-flex justify-content-center` to your `card-header`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card border-info" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="card-header text-white bg-info">
    <h6 class="mb-0">Example Title</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `d-inline` or `d-inline-block` class to h6

```
<div class="card border-info" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="card-header text-white bg-info">
<h6 class="d-inline-block align-middle">Example Title</h6>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
</div>
 </div>
```

this works for me

Comment: align-middle only works for inline and inline-block elements